# How to activate password policy to use Extended operation for password reset in OpenLDAP/windows

Tags: openldap, password-policy

I have created password policy by following procedure mentioned for OpenLDAP
But I don't observed its effect when I change password of user through extended operation. I get the response control but it has only warning instead of error.

So question is what is missing from my side ?
How to enforce password policy to use extended operation for resetting password ?
Once I define password policy would it be applicable for all existing users in OpenLDAP server? Or it will be applicable for new user only?

Comment: Have you defined a default policy object? And specified it as the default in the configuration?

Comment: And are you executing the change-password operation as the user himself? If you execute it as the ManagerDN it bypasses the policy overlay. You shouldn't use the ManagerDN account for anything yourself, that's for the server itself only.

Comment: @EJP: Yes. I have defined policy object and specified the same as default in configuration in slapd.conf as follows
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
ppolicy_use_lockout

Comment: @EJP - I am using your code posted on oracle forum [here] (https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157421). I am executing change-password operation as the user himself as follows 

`ExtendedRequest per = new PasswordExtendedRequest(ctx,"cn=bhal,dc=maxcrc,dc=com","Something1","Nothing123");
ExtendedResponse extRes = ExtendedResponse)ctx.extendedOperation(per);
  
ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=bhal,dc=maxcrc,dc=com");  ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Nothing123");
ctx.reconnect(new Control[]{new PasswordRequestControl(true)});`

Comment: VG. Can you answer my question about the account you're using?

Comment: @EJP - Do you mean account use for initialization process ? i.e. InitialLdapContext( ..) ? I am using ManagerDN for initialization. As if I use above user i.e cn=bhal,dc=maxcrc,dc=com for initialization then I get exception as follows while performing extendedOperation()


`javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; remaining name ''`

Comment: @EJP - As use case is Administrator resets the password of any user so is it not correct that ManagerDN is used to initialize before performing extendedOperation ?

Comment: I've already answered that. 'You shouldn't use the ManagerDN account for anything yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use the ManagerDN account for *anything* yourself. It bypasses all overlays and gives you infinite access to the DIT, which you don't want.

Your applications should run as users with entries in the DIT which are given appropriate permissions in the configuration.

I've defined admin *groups* for that, that all the applications and the human  administrators are part of, which makes the configuration simpler (and adding/changing admins or applications later *much* simpler). Mine goes something like this, in `slapd.conf` syntax: converting it to `slapd.d` online syntax is left as an exercise for the reader. Note that you'll have to change the base DNs etc to suit your own DIT, maybe the group classes and attribute names as well.

```
access to attrs=userPassword
    by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=XXX,dc=com" write
    by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=LDAP admins,ou=Groups,dc=XXX,dc=com" write
    by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=XXX,dc=com" write
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by * none

access to *
    by self write
    by dn="cn=Replicator,dc=XXX,dc=com,c=us" write
    by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=XXX,dc=com" write
    by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=LDAP admins,ou=Groups,dc=XXX,dc=com" write
    by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=XXX,dc=com" write
    by users read
    by anonymous search
    by * none
```

Note that this setup also allows users to change their own passwords, so you can now bind *as the user* when doing that.

Comment: Done with your suggested changes. But I am getting following error when trying to perform extendedOperation itself. 

`javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - Must supply old password to be changed as well as new one]; remaining name ''`

Also please note that we need to write generic code which would support all LDAP flavors such as Sun One LDAP, Tivoli , ADAM , Novell Directory services , Oracle Internet Directory etc. Would this approach work for all LDAP ?

Comment: EJP - Can you answer my question and take a look at the exception I am getting while performing extendedOperation ?

Comment: Just read the error message. You have to supply the old password as well as the new one. The extended request code I wrote supports that. Your UI should request the old password from the user and the new one. Typically you will request the new one twice to avoid typos. This approach will work with all LDAP servers that support the password-policy draft. Such a server will have a `supportedControl` attribute on the topmost entry with the value `1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1`.

Comment: But it's *not* relevant to my use case. How would a password administrator ( who is supposed to reset any user's password) would know old password of any user? It should only  ask for new password twice. Ideally following is expected by me.

1. Extended operation for change-password should ask **only** new password ( may be twice - second for reconfirmation) and should be successful. 

2. While next "bind" operation, it should get passwordExpiration Exception which means that user has to change his/her password immediately.

Comment: Take the case of AD, same use case works when pwdLastSet is set to 0 by Administrator and next bind operation receives passwordExpiration Exception. Same in case of all LDAP flavours with generic code.
I haven't see PasswordModifyExtendedRequest and PasswordModifyExtendedResponse classes in your code which may give me clear idea how this error 
is handled.Lastly, I am using Apache Directory Studio for LDAP browsing and I don't see 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 in supportedControl list of LDAP's root DSE. I wonder if I am on right track ??

Comment: If you're the password administrator you don't need to change the password at all. You just need to set `pwdReset`. The system will react accordingly, by giving you the appropriate extended response control value when the user signs in (binds), whereupon you need to insist that the *user* change his *own* password. If you want to generate a random password, the code I provided will do that too, by providing `null` as the new password: the server will then generate one for you and return it in the extended response control. Not a good feature and not one that I use or recommend.

Comment: Yes. That's works for OpenLDAP. I just set pwdReset to TRUE and got the error in response control as **changeAfterReset**.